# name Validation, logical error related to Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

```
function validator()
{
var f = document.forms.suform.elements.fn.value;
if(f==null || f=="" || f==" ") //condition 1
{
    alert("First name is required!");
    return false;
}
else if(!(/^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/,test(f))) // condition 2
{
    alert('Invalid First Name');
    return false;
}
    //Some other conditions
}
```

**I called it as**

```
<form method="post" name="suform" onsubmit="return validator()" action="register.php">
<input placeholder="First Name" name="fn" type="text" id="fname" maxlength=20>
    //other inputs
</form>
```

**Now the problem is condition 2 is not working and as long as it is there the conditions below it also dont work,
the second i delete condition 2 everything starts running fine.
There is some error in regex checking.**

Comment: You have a comma instead of a period between your regex and the test(f).

Comment: Thanks, i got frustrated looking for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(/^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/.test(f))
```

Period will come before the test()